# Photo Competition 2021-08-23: Cats

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Cats

Pictures of your cats. Kittens. Cats in baskets. Cats hanging from stuff. Cats in costumes. Cats with things on their heads. More kittens. Cats making funny expressions. Cats on fire, perhaps from attempts to shoot them by candlelight. Possibly lions. Cats, cats, cats.

This theme was suggested by [mattdm](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125915/photo-competition-2021-08-23-cats?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on September 6, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Comment: No fair! You finally pick cats and I'm away from home for 4 weeks.

Comment: @EricS Sorry about that. That's the way the cat lands. =)

Comment: I understand we're not supposed to downvote *answers* here, but is the *question* fair game? Asking for a friend.

Comment: @MichaelC Tell your friend to DV away. It is CW after all. =)

Comment: @scottbb CW = Cat Week?

Comment: @MichaelC Cat Wiki.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Pixel, focused

Another family member's cat (appropriately named "Pixel") that we fostered for two weeks. New environment, new discoveries, here fascinated by a furniture lift operating outside. The almost snake-like head droop intensifies the attention.

Canon EOS 70D + EF-S 35mm Macro, ISO800, f/3.5, 1/160s.

This little 35mm lens is overlooked, it changes your style.

[image]

Comment: I thought macro lenses where only used for macro shots?

Comment: Most macro lenses (except perhaps some very "hardcore" ones) can focus to infinity,  and so can be used as general purpose lenses. Of course macro lenses are optimized for "macro" (the lens above has a built-in lighting) but as prime lenses they are still better than your average zoom lens (as demonstrated above)(I have also used a 100mm macro for indoor sports because it's an f/2.8 lens, much faster than my zooms). In addition it's f/2.8 aperture also means that the camera can use its high-accuracy focus sensor.

Comment: My go-to portrait lens has been a 105mm Macro 1.8 for the better part of 20 years now.

Comment: @LightBender I'm forbidden to use such lenses for family portraits because they show all the skin defects... :)

Comment: Never had that problem, a little powder and 22 inch beauty dishes do wonders :), Granted, I did mostly fashion work, not family portraits

Answer (score 8):

[image]

*Neighbour cat on the tree branch.*

Canon 800D |
EF 70-300mm F4-F5.6 |
1/30 |
ISO 1600

Answer (score 6):

[image: Expert Review]

"Don't think this code will work, did you really test it?"

EOS M2, 22mm, f/2.0, 1/100, ISO100

Comment: or perhaps, "please start the build to warm up my seat, i.e., your keyboard"

Answer (score 5):

### Winter cat walk

My own cat. Taken in February of this year. Used my Sony RX10M3 at f/4, 1/125, 58.29mm at ISO125. No cool tricks, but I think her face in nicely in focus. :)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Lion]
Lion at Madikwe Game Reserve, South Africa keeping an eye on a few safari vehicles intermingled with the pride during late afternoon. The pride was unconcerned with the vehicles and went about their business of relaxing and yawning.

Dec 2012, Nikon D7000, 185mm, f/3.5, 1/60 sec, ISO 200

Answer (score 5):

**Spotting**

A jaguar taken at Yorkshire Wildlife Park, UK. August 2019.

Lumix FZ-72, ISO 400, 1/200s, F5.9 at 215mm

[image: A jaguar taken at Yorkshire Wildlife Park, UK]

Answer (score 4):

#### Pompom, looking into your soul.

Fostered by a family member while the owners were on vacation. A very shy animal, hidden most of the time I was there, so this photo is somehow the result of an in-house safari.

EOS 70D+Sigma 17-70mm Contemporary, ISO800, f/4, 1/125. Photo is a crop.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Dora the explorer**

She's a 13 year old tabby, who checked out every corner of the house when she arrived in 2008, hence the name.

Olympus OM-D E10 Mk III
f/1.7, ISO200 @ 25mm with a Lumix 25mm prime lens

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Too hot for Tygers

Tigers in the summer heat, Guilin, China.

[image]

Sony A700, Tamron 18-250mm
f/11, 104mm, ISO400, 1/90s

There is a sad tale to tell here. In Guilin in China there is the "Xiongsen Bear and Tiger Village." It purports to be a conservational incentive to save these two animals. The tourists, get to see more tigers and bears than you'd be likely to see in one place anywhere else, in a run down but not totally terrible setting. What they don't get to see is the large areas "offstage" with many tiger cages and bear enclosures where the animals are raised for the believed-medicinal properties of their various body parts.
When we visited we did not know this but it seemed likely that this was their intention. THe offstage areas were well hidden.  We did not get to see any of the performances which some web sites mention. Subsequent web searching reveals this operation is notorious and very well known internationally.

[Many related images with associated web pages](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=AOaemvLSntaiYIqdgWdIRFLTTu6xjYht0A:1630061454112&q=Xiongsen+Bear+and+Tiger+Village+%EF%BC%88North+Gate%EF%BC%89+Guilin&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecQYwS3w8sc9YSn_SWtOXmP05OIKzsgvd80rySypFLLmYoOy-KV4ubj10_UNS9LTzAzTi6QUlLh4PS7y8YtaKK9z1BLi5JywJK3y4xIzQdYipTjWZW_28ixiNY_IzM9LL07NU3BKTSxSSMxLUQjJTE8tUgjLzMlJTE9VeL-nwy-_qCRDwT2xJPX9nk4F99LMnMw8AOyFPaKXAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_q7yPhNHyAhVTbysKHc_vA1gQ6RN6BAg1EAE&biw=2088&bih=1175)

Answer (score 3):

### With a mouse I'd be finished already

[image: With a mouse I'd be finished already]
Panasonic DMC-FZ200, f=63mm (135 format equivalent), f/2.8, 1/60s, flash.

Germany 2019-03-18

Answer (score 3):

[image: The Lynx]

A lynx from a local wildlife park (2020-06-30)

Nikon D850

Sigma 150-600mm @ 600mm

f/6.3

1/640s

Comment: Can you add the exif info? SS, Apeture, iso and what body and lens you where using?

Comment: @JcbJoe: No problem, will do

Answer (score 2):

### "Touch not the Cat, bot a glove  "*

(but, actually, just yawning)

[image]

"Rover". Backyard.
Sony A6300 + Sony 70-300mm G.
f/4.5, 72 mm

*[Origin](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22touch+not+the+cat+bot+a+glove%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=AOaemvK7t5PLdCG8HkfUqZIFWFL3f_pIDQ:1630059549241&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwilmJSD_dDyAhUt3jgGHUH1AQAQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=2088&bih=1175&dpr=1.75)

Answer (score 2):

### That Cat with the Cigar Box Guitar

Anyone who performs with a cigar box guitar at paying gigs is one cool cat.

He's one of the coolest cats I know: "Microwave" Dave Gallaher of *'Microwave Dave & The Nukes'.*

[He normally plays a nice, newish Strat in conventional tuning or one of two fairly ancient Flying Vs for slide work, both of which are set up in open tuning in two different keys, during most of his gigs with The Nukes. He adds a recently new baritone Strat that he uses along with a suite of looping tools when doing his solo act. Dave also has a "Lowebow" made by renowned cigar box guitar luthier John Lowe of Memphis. It's a double broom-handle necked cigar box with a single bass string on one neck and two tenor strings on the other, which is usually played with a slide.]

[image]

<sub>Canon EOS 5D Mark III + EF 135mm f/2 L. ISO 6400, f/2.2, 1/125. Processed using Canon's *Digital Photo Professional 4* and downsized to 960x720 pixels for web viewing</sub>

Answer (score 2):

### Mowgli the Majestic

[image: Mowgli the Majestic]

iPhone X Portrait Mode, not edited
15 May 2021, 3:50pm, Melbourne, Florida

Answer (score 2):

**Moggy in the Park**
[image]

A cat in Bryant Park, New York City on a hot summer afternoon in 2018.

Canon 6D, 85mm, f/1.2, 1/320 second, ISO 400.

Answer (score 2):

### Siblings

[image: 15 seconds of peacefulness]
Sofa in Germany, 2019-12-01 on Sony DSC-R1, 44.7mm/4.5, 1/50s with flash.

Answer (score 2):

### Stable Genius

[image: A cat sitting on a bay of hale]
Barn in Germany, Sony DSC-R1 on 2019-09-06, 29.2mm/6.3, ISO160, 1/50s with bounced flash.

Answer (score 1):

### The lion petting zoo

A lion at the [Safari Park Open Zoo in Kanchanaburi](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g297924-d1744252-Reviews-Safari_Park_Open_Zoo-Kanchanaburi_Kanchanaburi_Province.html), Thailand. I took the photo in July of 2017 with a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge at ƒ/1.7, 1/286, 4.2 mm and ISO40.

The picture quality or composition aren't particularly interesting, but I think the situation might be. Like the linked Trip Advisor reviews for the zoo, both the picture and keeping a lion this way are certainly controversial. Posting the picture isn't an endorsement of the practice yet it provides an insight into a world you may never see otherwise.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### One Bad Harp Blowin' Cat

Roguie Ray LaMontagne¹ is the coolest harmonica blowing cat I've ever met. Over the years he's performed with everyone from Muddy Waters to Billy Joe Shaver, Johnny Cash to Warren Haynes, Leon Russell to Bela Fleck, John Prine to Delbert McClinton, David Allen Coe to Dickey Betts, and a whole lot of others. I caught him in 2017 sitting in with New Orleans based 'Big Al & The Heavyweights' at the W.C. Handy Music Festival held each year in "The Shoals" area of Alabama (The "Quad-Cities" of Muscle Shoals, Florence, Tuscumbia, and Sheffield).

[image]

<sub>Canon EOS 5D Mark III + EF 135mm f/2 L. ISO 6400, f/2.2, 1/125. Processed with Canon's *Digital Photo Professional 4* before downsizing for web viewing.</sub>

Hanging out with Roguie Ray after a 2019 show.

[image]

<sub>¹ Yes, he's the more well know Ray LaMontagne's father, though the elder Ray and the younger Ray's Mom split up shortly after the younger was born in 1973 and his mother allowed very little to no contact between them as he grew up with his six step-siblings. There were times when she didn't even let Roguie know in what state she and his son were living.</sub>